# Tools for automated qa testing

Tags: test-automation

I was searching on the AppExchange for automated testing programs:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000ptkwEAA

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4fpTEAR

I also found an article on Selenium at Salesforce. How does Selenium interface with Salesforce? The app exchange programs have a GUI within Salesforce, but I'm not clear how Selenium works.

Any feedback on the above tools would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't used the other tools (and I do hope you get a fair feedback on those tools), I can comment on Selenium. The primary function of Selenium is to make sure that clicks, inputs, and so on result in the correct behavior. As such, this is well-suited for testing the visual aspects of Visualforce, especially if you rely heavily on jQuery, backbone, angular, etc.

Do not rely on Selenium validating the minor details, such as verifying that some Apex Code logic was correct. This is the job of unit tests in Apex Code, and should be tested as such, since you need code coverage, and since unit tests in Apex Code are naturally insulated from live data and should never affect live data even when not isolated.

Note that, like all web-based testing, changes made by Selenium are permanent. Live data *may be* affected by using Selenium. You must therefore take care to create any records that can be later cleaned up. If your test is interrupted mid-session, you may end up having to clean up a mess. That's another reason why I've suggested that you focus your efforts on plain unit tests. What is easily done cannot easily be undone in the event of catastrophic failure.

Selenium interacts with Salesforce by controlling a browser process on your computer. It runs locally on your computer, spawning a new browser process, then simulating keyboard and mouse events directly within the browser. You can also write more advanced tests directly in Java that run on the Selenium framework, allowing you to do things like querying the database to verify the results of the interaction, cleaning up data, etc.

It's great to be able to verify that your Visualforce pages are not broken (e.g. you can no longer click on a link because it's missing, or was rendered wrong, etc), and it can help track regression issues with the UI itself. Used appropriately, it can be a line of defense against unintended behavior changes introduced while working on new JavaScript, Visualforce, etc, as well as detecting changes that may have occurred because of static resource changes or links to CDN's changing.

Answer (score 1):

On Selenium testing...

Before deciding to test at the UI-level - Selenium automates clicks and can assert the results of those clicks - bear in mind that the return you get from such testing may not be worth the cost. In particular if your application is changing frequently, you may find that a lot of time is going into maintaining the scripts, particularly if they are created using simple recording techniques. If your pages are normal Salesforce default layout or basic Visualforce with no added JavaScript, then also bear in mind that Salesforce tests the platform and there is no need for you to re-test it.

However, if you are writing a lot of complex UI and mixing in 3rd party JavaScript libraries and want to be sure your app works on many platforms then Selenium tests may pay-back. Companies such as https://www.browserstack.com/ allow you to run your Selenium tests across many browsers (Selenium Grid) including all the mobile ones, so each test can be executed in many browsers automatically.

But as sfdcfox says, unit tests are the place to focus and only if something can't be properly tested there should you consider using UI-level tests.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce testing would mean testing all the integrations to the Salesforce application as well. Dynamic workflow/integration testing is super complex and adding performance to the dimension makes it more complicated!

Check out Fusion Systems ITAS. It is totally scriptless and covers integration, regression and performance testing apart from just functional testing. Really cutting edge!

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000DpSm7EAF

http://fusionsystemsinc.com/salesforce/